# Get variable value from code behind and use in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Variable in .aspx.cs file

```
public string apmt_val { get; set; }
```

I want to use this in .aspx page as

```
if(<%#apmt_val%> == "Some Value"){
  // Do something
}
else{
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: You have stated a goal but not a problem/question.

Comment: You might need to pass data from backend to Front end by Using ViewBag....

Answer (score 0):

field must be declared public or protected

Then, to call it on the ASPX side:

> <%=apmt_val %>

Note that this won't work if you place it on a server tag attribute. For example:

> <asp:Label runat="server" Text="<%=apmt_val %>" />

Your Solution

> <%if (this.apmt_val == "Some Value") { %>    //logic  <%}%>

Answer (score 0):

<%if (this.yourvar == "value") { %> //set the logic here <%}%>